# How to test messaging services?

Tags: test-design

I have to test a messaging service and would like to know if there are any proven techniques developed specifically to test messaging services. I know that for example JMeter has JMS support. That would cover load/performance testing. However, I'm not looking for tools but for concepts and techniques.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you consider a technique to be proven if it has been shown to find bugs.  I also assume you are interested in messaging in the backend system sense, not in the instant messaging sense.

A network partition test is a test in which network connections between nodes in a distributed system are temporarily severed.  [Aphyr](https://aphyr.com/posts) has a series of blog posts describing network partition tests of distributed systems.  You may be particularly interested in the post on [RabbitMQ](https://aphyr.com/posts/315-jepsen-rabbitmq), and the Kafka posts [here](https://aphyr.com/posts/293-jepsen-kafka) and [here](https://aphyr.com/posts/297-jepsen-strangeloop-hangout).